Donated INSendMessageIntent is not showing in Share Extension
I am trying to support share suggestions from message conversations in my app's Share extension. The conversation suggestions seem to appear on my iPad but are not appearing on my iPhone or several other iPhone's which I have tested on. The app is a universal app. I followed the instructions in the Apple docs.

The main app info.plist contains the appropriate NSUserActivityTypes: INSendMessageIntent
The Share Extension contains IntentsSupported: INSendMessageIntent
The code to donate the intent seems to be properly working and does not report any errors in the completion block.

Even a new project created with the latest version of xcode (Version 15.3 (15E204a)) seems to have the same issue.
Main App info.plist

Share Extension info.plist

Donate intent code:
private func donateIntent(chatName: String, chatID: String, groupImage: INImage?) {
    let groupName = INSpeakableString(spokenPhrase: chatName)
    let intent = INSendMessageIntent(
        recipients: nil, outgoingMessageType: .outgoingMessageText, content: nil,
        speakableGroupName: groupName, conversationIdentifier: chatID, serviceName: nil, sender: nil,
        attachments: nil)

    if let groupImage = groupImage {
        intent.setImage(groupImage, forParameterNamed: \.speakableGroupName)
    }

    let interaction = INInteraction(intent: intent, response: nil)
    interaction.donate { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error donating intent: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Successfully donated sendMessage intent.")
        }
    }
}


I have modified your code. Please try this code It works for me.
private func donateIntent(chatName: String, chatID: String, groupImage: INImage?) {
    let groupName = INSpeakableString(spokenPhrase: chatName)
    let intent = INSendMessageIntent(
        recipients: nil, content: nil,
        speakableGroupName: groupName, conversationIdentifier: chatID, serviceName: nil, sender: nil,
        attachments: nil)

    if let groupImage = groupImage {
        intent.setImage(groupImage, forParameterNamed: \.speakableGroupName)
    }

    let interaction = INInteraction(intent: intent, response: nil)
    interaction.donate { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error donating intent: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Successfully donated sendMessage intent.")
        }
    }
}

